# How to Build Skia library Project with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, skia

Thank you for reading my question.

I want to build skia library using VS2012, but skia's master branch support only vs2013 or higher version.

I tried to search old revision that can be builded with vs2012, but I cannot search that version.

please help me.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Get a compiler that supports all C++11 features.
- Check out an older branch of Skia.